# Denying certain UIViews from rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a UIView that I don't want rotating when I go into landscape mode. I don't, however, want to deny the entire View Controller from rotating, because I have certain items that need to rotate. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check this answer from Apple Q&A it must help you !   [disable rotation for a specific uiview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1890/_index.html)

this function is what you are looking for :

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{   
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        // do whatever
    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context)
    { 

    }];

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

Comment: I'm using the code from the link you provided and it works. The view is maintaining it's shape, but not it's position. I have it constrained to the top of the phone(by the front facing camera), but it moves to the center. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!